# Why do dictionary values get set to zero in while loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to prepare for an interview and wanted to make a dictionary for the count of each letter in a sentence.

I was quite surprised to discover I might have a scoping problem, or what seems like one.

For my specific approach below, I wasn't sure why it wasn't working until I found that elem is being set to nothing in the while loop. But since it is nested within the for loop that references elem, I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
s = 'letters and stuff'
def d_count(s):
    dic = {}
    i = 0
    s1 = set(s)
    s2 = list(s)
    for elem in s1:
        dic[elem] = 0
        j = 0
        while (i < len(s2)):
            #elem disappears here
            if s2[i] == elem:
                j = j+1
                dic[elem] = j
            i = i + 1
    return dic
print(d_count(s))
```

Result

```
{' ': 2, 's': 0, 'n': 0, 'u': 0, 'l': 0, 'f': 0, 'd': 0, 't': 0, 'r': 0, 'a': 0, 'e': 0}
```

Desired Result

```
{' ': 2, 's': 2, 'n': 1, 'u': 1, 'l': 1, 'f': 2, 'd': 1, 't': 3, 'r': 1, 'a': 1, 'e': 2}
```

Comment: I'd expect `i = 0` should be immediately before the `while i <`

Comment: @o11c: That answers the question. Make it a proper answer. Or better, fix that code to use a `for` loop over the characters instead of a `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you need to reset `i` to zero within the for loop:

```
def d_count(s):
    dic = {}
    s1 = set(s)
    s2 = list(s)
    for elem in s1:
        i = j = dic[elem] = 0
        while (i < len(s2)):
            if s2[i] == elem:
                j += 1
                dic[elem] = j
            i += 1
    return dic

>>> print(d_count(s))
{' ': 2, 'r': 1, 'f': 2, 't': 3, 's': 2, 'a': 1, 'n': 1, 'd': 1, 'l': 1, 'e': 2, 'u': 1}
```

Note that even with this fix, your solution is still `O(n**2)` because you go through the list in full for each character in the list.

Using `Counter` in an interview is just a throw away to show that you know you could use it.  The interviewer would be expecting a different approach.  Here is one such method that is `O(n)`.

```
def d_count(s):
    d = {}
    for char in s:
        d[char] = d.get(char, 0) + 1
    return d

>>> print(d_count(s))
{'l': 1, 'e': 2, 't': 3, 'r': 1, 's': 2, ' ': 2, 'a': 1, 'n': 1, 'd': 1, 'u': 1, 'f': 2}
```

Here is an alternative method using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which is also `O(n)`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def d_count(s):
    dd = defaultdict(int)
    for char in s:
        dd[char] += 1
    return dict(dd)

>>> print(d_count(s))
{'l': 1, 'e': 2, 't': 3, 'r': 1, 's': 2, ' ': 2, 'a': 1, 'n': 1, 'd': 1, 'u': 1, 'f': 2}
```

Comment: The whole issue of the `i = 0` assignment can be avoided by using a `for` loop iterating over the characters, instead of a `while` loop. Simple is better than complex. That obviously does not improve the runtime, though.

Comment: `i = j = dic[elem] = 0`? D: I agree with @JanChristophTerasa, no need to make a mess.

Comment: All three variables (`i`, `j` and `dic[elem]`) are set to zero.

Comment: `for c in s:` instead of `while i < len(s2)` The `s2 = list(s)` is unnecessary as well

Comment: I know they're set to 0, I'm saying it's kinda horrific. Even spread out on multiple lines it would be slightly better...

Comment: I would not use the first solution.  The point of it is to correct the OPs error so that it is usable but still as close as possible to the OPs original solution.

Comment: I tought helping for an interview might also mean helping with style, but you are right, it's probably better to just fix the original issue.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I disagree. I see no reason to skip a small design/style thing which costs nothing.

Comment: I would argue that it depends or readability.  If the variable names are short and there are not too many, then certainly yes.  For example, please review https://dev.to/duomly/the-best-practices-of-coding-in-python-and-what-to-avoid-3c65.  In fact, it makes the code more maintainable, as one could just change a single value if the default value of zero were to change instead of changing several lines of code.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'letters and stuff'
c = Counter(s)
print(Counter(s))
# Counter({'t': 3, 'e': 2, 's': 2, ' ': 2, 'f': 2, 'l': 1, 'r': 1, 'a': 1, 'n': 1, 'd': 1, 'u': 1})
```

Comment: If you want to count something, use `Counter`.  This is a great solution in practice for the task at hand, but not appropriate in an interview setting.

Comment: Likely true, but depends on the interviewer. Knowing the stdlib of a language might also be a good idea. It's probably best do be able to have both solutions at hand.

Comment: I would certainly mention that one _could_ use `Counter`, but that you (the interviewer) are probably looking for something that demonstrates further knowledge.

Comment: The knowledge of the existence of Counter certainly seems like a better proxy for "knows and understands their tools" than an ad-hoc informally-specified bug-ridden slow implementation of Counter.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
 for elem in s1:
    dic[elem] = 0
    j = 0
    elem_copy = elem
    while (i < len(s2)):
        if s2[i] == elem_copy:
            j = j+1
            dic[elem_copy] = j
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: `elemCopy` -> `elem_copy`

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thank you :)

Comment: You’re welcome, no problem. I would have edited it, but I felt guilty clogging up the review queues for such a tiny change, if I could have even submitted something so short in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
d = {i: s.count(i) for i in s}
```

Comment: Never use this in an interview, if ever...  It is very slow compared to alternative methods which are `O(n)`.

Comment: Each time you use `count`, you need to traverse the entire list.  Doing this on the set of letters is `s` is an improvement (assuming there are some duplicates), but it is still far from ideal.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'letters and stuff'
def d_count(s):
    dic = {}

    for element in s:
        dic[element] = s.count(element)
        set(dic)

    return dic
print(d_count(s))
```

Output: {'l': 1, 'e': 2, 't': 3, 'r': 1, 's': 2, ' ': 2, 'a': 1, 'n': 1, 'd': 1, 'u': 1, 'f': 2}

Comment: Same comment: Never use this in an interview, if ever... It is very slow compared to alternative methods which are `O(n)`.

Comment: Really? O.o
and I thought the way you did it could be slower!
but in fact it would go through the vector twice.
cool, thanks!

Comment: I showed two methods.  The first one corrected the error in the OPs code, but it is still not an ideal solution. The second solution is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solutions adhering to the ["Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" mantra](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp), basically emulating the [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) functionality:

```
s = 'letters and stuff'
d = {}
for c in s:
    try:
        d[c] += 1
    except KeyError:
        d[c] = 1
print(d)
# {'l': 1, 'e': 2, 't': 3, 'r': 1, 's': 2, ' ': 2, 'a': 1, 'n': 1, 'd': 1, 'u': 1, 'f': 2}
```

Alternatively check for the existence of the key:

```
s = 'letters and stuff'
d = {}
for c in s:
    if c in d:
        d[c] += 1
    else:
        d[c] = 1
print(d)
# {'l': 1, 'e': 2, 't': 3, 'r': 1, 's': 2, ' ': 2, 'a': 1, 'n': 1, 'd': 1, 'u': 1, 'f': 2}
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't figured out why that does not work. But if it helps, this solves the problem and gives the desired result

```py
s = 'letters and stuff'
def d_count(s):
    dic = {}
    s1 = set(s)
    s2 = list(s)
    for elem in s1:
        dic[elem] = 0
        j = 0
        for i in xrange(0,len(s2)):
            if s2[i] == elem:
                j = j+1
                dic[elem] = j
    return dic
print(d_count(s))
```

Comment: Same comment again: Never use this in an interview, if ever... It is very slow compared to alternative methods which are `O(n)`.  For each character in `s`, your method requires traversing the entire list again which is `O(n**2)`.

Comment: Why are you using Python 2 for this?

Comment: You can iterate over the characters directly, there is no need for `xrange` or creating `s2` at all.